# jQuery or js check if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to make checkbox fire an alert if it is checked.
This is my code below. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var $isgdpr = $("#isgdpr").is(':checked');
if ($isgdpr) {
  alert('Checked!');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="isgdpr" checked="checked">
</label>
```

Comment: I placed your code in a snippet, where it works absolutely fine. If you're expecting this to work when the checkbox is changed, place your code in a `change` event handler.

Comment: Its not popping up alert box when i check the checkbox. Not even your corrected code for me (I ran the snippet).

Comment: As I stated above, it only runs on load. If you want the logic to runs when the checkbox is changed you need to wrap your code in a change event handler. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: I have expanded this question. Should I open a new thread?

Comment: The question hasn't changed. Unless you're intending to ask about a completely different topic you don't need to open anything. Have you read the duplicate I marked yet? Or even the answer below? Both solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code work on page load but if you want to run it on check/uncheck of checkbox, you should put it in `onchange` event handler of checkbox

```
$("#isgdpr").change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    alert('Checked!');
});
```

```js
$("#isgdpr").change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    console.log('Checked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="isgdpr">
</label>
```